# Creating .I file in C

Tags: c

Sir pls tell me how to create .I file (extended source file) in c

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what you want.

Comment: do you mean expand the macro? you can try the gcc -E -o main.I main.c

Comment: Oh ... welcome to SO. Sorry about the hard reply (but get used to it) and, most important, have fun!

Answer (score 4):

A common way to create files in `C` is with the `fopen()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *handle;
handle = fopen("extended.I", "w");
if (handle != NULL) {
    /* ... */
    fclose(handle);
}
```

Comment: no this is not my answer

Comment: given the ambiguity of the query, this seems like a perfectly sane (and correct) answer.

Answer (score 4):

Terribly vague question, but it sounds like you are using Visual Studio.  Right-click your project, Properties, C/C++, Preprocessor, change "Generate Preprocessed File" to Yes.

After you rebuild, you'll get the .i files with the preprocessor output in your project directory.

Comment: +1 my vague question translator indicates this is probably what he is after

Comment: I want one of those vague question translators ( +1 ).

Answer (score 3):

arsane's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760651/creating-i-file-in-c#comment3977866_3760651) is the correct response if you are on Linux. "To expand the macro, you can try

```
gcc -E -o main.I main.c
```

"

When using the gcc compiler system, it is possible to halt the compiler system at particular phases by using compiler flags.  `-E` for .i files, `-S` for .s files (an assembly language version of the program)

From the gcc man page:

```
  -E  Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler proper.
       The output is in the form of preprocessed source code, which is
       sent to the standard output.

       Input files which don't require preprocessing are ignored.
```

Answer (score -3):

The following command will create a `.i` file from a `.c` file

```
cc -E main.c -o main.i
```